# Set pageIndex in Angular material paginator not working when page loaded for first time

Tags: angular, angular-material, paginator

I want Angular's Paginator starts from second page when page refreshed but I got this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'pageIndex' of undefined
```

I tried to use delay but it is not a good solution,

HTML

```
<mat-paginator #paginator
  showFirstLastButtons
  [length]="length"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
  (page)="pageEvent = changePage($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

TypeScript

```
  @ViewChild('paginator', { static: true }) paginator;
  pageSize = 5;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 50, 100];
  pageEvent: PageEvent;
  buttonDisablity = true;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.paginator.pageIndex = 2;
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ngOnInit` hook doesn't have access of `viewchild` instance. `ViewChild` instance is available only in or after `afterViewInit` hook.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.paginator.pageIndex = 2;
}
```